# Why does this program segfault?

Tags: linux, assembly

I do not understand. Furthermore, the most amazing thing is: this program segfaults when I run it from the terminal, but does not segfault in gdb. Thus, while I'd love to show gdb output, I can't, as it is not interesting, and seems to be doing exactly what I want.

```
[OP@localhost sys_brk]$ cat out_of_memory.s 
    .section .text
    .globl _start

_start:
    mov $12, %rax # sys_brk
    mov $0x1000000, %rdi
    syscall 

    # i: index of memory we are writing to (%rax)
    mov $0x403000, %rax
evil_loop_start:
    cmp $0x1000000, %rax
    jge evil_loop_end

    mov %rax, (%rax)
    add $0x8, %rax
    jmp evil_loop_start
evil_loop_end:
    mov $34, %rax # sys_pause
    syscall
```

Comment: PROBABLY: the gdb does prevent ASLR (Address space layout randomization), so your hardcoded memory address `0x403000` does work in it, but under normal shell your executable is by default by that OS installation treated as PIE and ASLR-ed into some random area of virtual memory space. Check your current OS and built binary (`uname -a` , `file <your_binary>` and depends how you link it) and google what are the defaults for your OS+toolchain, if ASLR and PIE is enabled by default. There are also many questions on SO dealing with trivial "buffer overflow" experiments = advice how to switch OFF.

Comment: Did you make sure to `set disable-randomization off` in `gdb` before running the program?

Comment: Ahh.. I see. It seems to be as you guys said: ASLR was default off in gdb.